# What is a more concise expression of "did what she said she'd do"?

Tags: word-choice, concision

I'm trying to express my gratitude for someone who "followed through on" the things she said she would do, without using idiomatic expressions. To me "did what you said you would do" and "followed through with/on" sound casual and colloquial. I'm sure there's a better, more refined way of conveying the same information without sounding unsophisticated or common.

I want to thank someone who actually did their job and resolved an issue--from start to finish--and didn't simply pay lip service (I could also use help with that idiom, too), when the culture of her work place rewards contempt, apathy, indolence, and gas-lighting.

I've searched online for similar phrases, the definition of the phrases themselves, articles about the importance of doing what you say you will do and following through, hoping to gain some insight. So far, I've found synonyms like "complete," "implement," "carry out," "accomplish," "achieve," "comply," "adhere," "engage in," etc. However, they don't really convey the mood and sentiment I'm trying to express. I suppose I'm looking for a near antonym or a word or phrase related to "renege."

The following are just a few of sites I visited:

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/follow+through
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/follow%20through%20on%2Fwith
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/follow-through-on-with
https://thesaurus.yourdictionary.com/follow-through
https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/follow_through.html
https://www.skipprichard.com/aim-higher-the-importance-of-doing-what-you-say-you-will-do/
https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/doing%20as%20one%20says

Can anyone help me? I welcome any and all suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the phrases you have given as examples. Why not pick one of them?

Comment: Be careful! If you thank someone explicitly for doing what they promised, this embodies the negative implication that you doubted them. In a letter I would just thank them and emphasize the positive consequences of their actions. At a later stage you may be able to explain in person that others were all talk.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with "complete," "implement," "carry out," "accomplish," "achieve," "comply," "adhere," "engage in"?

Answer (score 2):

***Keep one's word*** is an expression that means

> to fulfil one's promise
>
> - I said I'd meet the deadline, and ***I kept my word***. ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/keep-ones-word))

You can also use ***be [faithful](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/faithful#:%7E:text=true%20to%20one%27s%20word%2C%20promises,of%20duty%3A%20a%20faithful%20worker.)/true to one's word***

> doing what one said one would do : keeping one's promise
>
> - He said he would help, and he ***was true to his word***. ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/true%20to%20one%27s%20word#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20true%20to%20one%27s,was%20true%20to%20his%20word.))

Comment: That's very close to what I want to say, but not quite. "True to one's word" has a connotation of, I don't know...morality? It seems like a phase one would use with their friends and family, as opposed to a more professional or academic setting.